# Jasper trim chars if goes beyond width of TextField for CSV export

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing an issue for Jasper, I am trying export data to CSV with the help of JRCsvExporter. The issue is I am having width for one of the TextField is 5 chars but if data comes with > 5 chars, then it is not truncating to 5 chars.

I want to restrict this data to only 5 chars.

I have the option to do substring but I don't want to use that. Is there any way to configure to set at Jasper side to truncate or restrict data to only 5 chars.

I tried with

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="Boolean.TRUE"/> <br> 
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.full" value="Boolean.TRUE"/>
```

But this is truncating only when there is space else it is showing entire content. I cannot trust on this property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What do u mean by *have the option to do substring but I don't want to use that*?

To substring a data in Jasper, in Textfield Expression, simply use

`$F{field}.substring(5)`

to substring into 5 chars.

Comment: @ ggDeGreat, thanks for your response. I am looking something like out of the box. Because we have lot of reports and some are exporting to TXT and some are in CSV format. Truncating fine for TXT export file based on 'width' attribute, but for CSV there is a specific requirement to truncate the chars. I am looking it should truncate for CSV as well.